# VB.NET: showing DATE in datagridview bound in a database error

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I bind table A from mySQL database to a datagridview. One of its columns is "in_Date" with data type DATE(). An exception says

> String was not recognized as valid DateTime.Couldn't <> store in
>   in_Date column. Expected type is DateTime.

Here's my code in connection:

```
Dim myconn as MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
myconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=pw; database=db"
Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlAdapter 
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim bind As New BindingSource 
myconn.Open()
Dim command as MySqlCommand ("select * from db.A;")
adapter.SelectCommand = command 
adapter.Fill(table) 
bind.DataSource = table 
MyDGV.DataSource = bind 
adapter.Update(table)
myConn.close()
```

The table is yet empty. It was fine before when my columns are only in either varchar or int data types. How can I do that with DATE? I don't know what is the problem and how I can solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to store: Date, the date and time, do you want to save milliseconds or just seconds?

Comment: The date only. e.g. 2016-02-07 but ok with other date formats too. I'll edit my post, thanks. @Plutonix

Comment: where exactly do you get the exception?  The error you listed sounds like something somewhere is still using strings in place of DateTime types, but there is other code that looks wrong.

Comment: oh, I just found it. Yes it was somewhere in computing the total of rows and columns' values. Thank you!  @Plutonix